# How to remove mailbox limit size in Plesk

Tags: email-server

My mailbox is currently limited to 97mbs. I would like to make this unlimited, as it is with other domains on my server.

I have tried to mailling specity a new size, but anything over `97mbs` says `"Incorrect limit value was specified"`.

In short, i can't go past 97mbs and I would like to remove this limit.

I don't mind having to use command line if necessary.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like is "Mailbox size limit" from template/hosting plan is effects your domain/subscription.

You can ask your hoster/reseller, of if you server owner check for limits in domain, domain template or hosting plan settings.

Comment: Got it to update in the end, but the documentation on the issue is awful.